# Why can't I put a constant into an CGRectMake?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have tried this:

```
CGRectMake(0.0f, kFooBarHeight, 100.0f, 10.0f);
```

I get an error `unexpected ';' before ')'`, and `too few arguments for CGRectMake`. When I exchange this with:

```
CGFloat foo = kFooBarHeight;
CGRectMake(0.0f, foo, 100.0f, 10.0f);
```

then all is fine. Are constants not suitable to pass along as parameters?

Comment: I suspect no one can tell you what is going on unless you include the definition of kFooBarHeight.

Comment: funny. try posting the kFooBarHeight definition

Comment: why are you putting the 'f' after the constants - when i uses constants i never includes the f??

Comment: @all: I had an semikolon there, which was bad.

Comment: @zPesk: the "f" means "float". If you don't write it, you may have a double. 10 = integer. 10.0f = float. 10.0 = double. hope this helps :)

Answer (score 15):

Without the kFooBarHeight definition it's impossible to give a good answer but I'm guessing you defined kFooBarHeight using a preprocessor definition? If so, best guess is you added a semicolon to the end. Your definition should look like this: `#define kFooBarHeight 10` but you have set as: `#define kFooBarHeight 10;` .

If what you have is the second definition when it replaced by the preprocessor you get:

```
CGRectMake(0.0f, 10;, 100.0f, 10.0f);
```

That's why your second example works correctly, it expands to:

```
CGFloat foo = 10;;
CGRectMake(0.0f, foo, 100.0f, 10.0f);
```

Again, this is just an educated guess, it's impossible to say without the actual definition of kFooBarHeight.

Answer (score 3):

Change your

```
#define kFooBarHeight 100;
```

to

```
#define kFooBarHeight 100
```

Semicolons should not be used to terminate #defines unless you know for certain how it will be used.